# Unique QR Code for a certain system only

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio-2010, qr-code

I have a question about QR Codes, specifically about certain uses. So I am planning to develop a system that uses a QR code as a security measure for an Identification Card (ID). I decided to use this method because of its low-cost fashion requirements. In fact I already have my encoder and decoder (thanks to the existing libraries today).

Now my dilemma is; QR Codes seem to be at reach by almost everyone, they could be used and even be exploited. My point is, how can I make my QR Codes unique, so that other decoders can't read them (other than mine), you know, for security reasons. Is there a way to do so? Or other methods to secure my QR Code?

Here's my idea:

```
Scan ID Card with QR Code function()

if(My Unique QR Code Decoded == Value from Database)
{
  allow entry();
}
else if(Similar QR Code but-not-made-by-me Decoded != Value from Database)
{
  deny entry();
}
```

Your thoughts are very much appreciated! I'm doing it in C#.

Comment: That completely depends on what you're trying to defend against.  It sounds like you actually just want to encrypt or sign your data.

Comment: You could encrypt the data with a private key before encoding into the QR code. Anyone trying to scan it would get garbage, but your application would scan, then decrypt.

Comment: Encrypting/hashing the data before creating the QR code would solve the problem of storing "plaintext" (e.g. user's name) on the card, but note that that information is often on the card anyway. The *whole point* of QR codes is that they're easy to read, so whatever you do someone could potentially take a picture  of the ID card and trivially duplicate the code.

Comment: Is Encryption the best I could do? I'm troubled with someone duplicating the code. That wouldn't be nice and bring lots of problems.